# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Project Management Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Who decides how much work should be included in each Sprint?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/who-decides-how-much-work-should-be-included-in-each-sprint)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to present a "customer impacted" issue to senior management?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9635/how-to-present-a-customer-impacted-issue-to-senior-management)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [At what point does a user story get tested in an iteration?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9657/at-what-point-does-a-user-story-get-tested-in-an-iteration)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Does the team estimate time for tasks or stories or both?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/does-the-team-estimate-time-for-tasks-or-stories-or-both)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How can my team reconcile flow and pair-programming?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9694/how-can-my-team-reconcile-flow-and-pair-programming)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Which Scrum certification provider is most widely recognized or accepted?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/which-scrum-certification-provider-is-most-widely-recognized-or-accepted)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Introducing fun at work for Software Engineering team](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9712/introducing-fun-at-work-for-software-engineering-team)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Members of the Broader Team Find the PMO Burdensome and Valueless](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9618/members-of-the-broader-team-find-the-pmo-burdensome-and-valueless)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What should be the methodology followed by a research and development project?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9722/what-should-be-the-methodology-followed-by-a-research-and-development-project)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Role of a technical project manager?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9588/role-of-a-technical-project-manager)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)