# Answer has been posted and answer count is now correct but sort order is *still* incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, meta

An answer was posted for [Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/lets-get-critical-sep-2013-site-self-evaluation) on 2013-09-23 03:00:57Z. However, the [Questions section](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) is still showing **0 answers** even after 8 hours.

Screenshot given below:

[image]

Same behavior on Chrome, Chrome (incognito), and IE 10.

**Update**:

Now the answer count is correct but the **modified datetime and sort order is still incorrect**. On the active tab, this post should be displayed at the second spot but it is still displayed on the third row. This post was modified (answer added) on Sep 23 (not Sep 16 as captured in the screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Maybe *community* answers doesn't count? I really don't know, just wondering...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right. The specific code path used to create the automated Community answer was not updating the question metadata correctly.

This has been fixed though will only manifest going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that, until last night, the answer wasn't upvoted. A question is generally considered "answered" when it has at least one positively scored answer.

The answer was accepted, so I'm not sure if that should count as answered or not. However, it now shows as answered now that the answer is positively scored.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look into it. But how do we explain the reason why "Site Self-Eval" post is listed below the "Common PM Challenges" post? Even though the page is sorted by "most recent activity". I think that is a bug

Comment: Good question. I suspect it might be because the Community user isn't a real user.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a comment on this from a SE dev?

Comment: It's a different, yet related bug. I'll point this out to the community team and let them take it from here. I don't wanna keep bugging the developers as Oded already looked at this and marked it as [meta-tag:status-norepro].

Comment: Thanks for the follow up

Comment: I asked Oded to look at this again. The answer count is most likely a caching issue, but the "last modified" timestamp may be a bug.